# Can html2pdf 3.0.4 convert complex html file?

Tags: itext, java-7, pdfhtml

I have a html file draw a donut chart by canvas like below (it not done yet) and I want to convert it to pdf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Blayn-report</title>
  <style>

  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="chart" width="500" height="500" style="background-color:white"> </canvas>


  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("chart");
    var chart = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function drawdountChart(canvas) {

      this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.lineWidth, this.strockStyle, this.from, this.to = null;
      this.set = function (x, y, radius, from, to, lineWidth, strockStyle) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        this.strockStyle = strockStyle;
      }

      this.draw = function (data) {
        canvas.beginPath();
        canvas.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
        canvas.strokeStyle = this.strockStyle;
        canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.from, this.to);
        canvas.stroke();
        var numberOfParts = data.numberOfParts;
        var parts = data.parts.pt;
        var colors = data.colors.cs;
        var df = Math.PI * 1.5;
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++) {
          canvas.beginPath();
          canvas.strokeStyle = colors[i];
          canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, df, df + (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100));
          canvas.stroke();
          df += (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100);
        }
      }
    }

    var data =
    {
      numberOfParts: 2,
      parts: { "pt": [45, 55] },//percentage of each parts 
      colors: { "cs": ["green", "yellow"] }//color of each part
    };

    var drawDount = new drawdountChart(chart);
    drawDount.set(150, 150, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, 30, "#fff");
    drawDount.draw(data);



  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I try to convert it using html2pdf 3.0.4, the output file was empty. But when I change the html file to simple file with only text and no js, it work fine.

So my question is:

- Does html2pdf can convert complex file with js?
- If html2pdf can't convert complex file, which library should I use to do that? I have already think about write the pdf file my self but it will be very complex. Any other suggestion solution about this will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: From the Horse's mouth 
">When I try to convert it using html2pdf 3.0.4, the output file was empty. But when I change the HTML file to a simple file with only text and no-js, it works fine." so Obvious it cannot handle the raw format.

You can try the Google Doc way where you basically render it as an image and then use that image in the HTML2PDF plugin..

Or switch to CloudConvert  
https://github.com/cloudconvert/cloudconvert-node

Comment: @NishantSVispute I will give it a try. Thank you